# How to set up collation for MongoDB collection storing mixed content?

Tags: mongodb, collation

I'm using MongoDB 4.4 Enterprise.

I have a collection which stores mixed language content. More precisely, some of the fields hold both English and Arabic text, such fields are the description or name or title etc.

My question is how should I properly set up collation? I mean, I know I can specify collation for each collection at creation time, but that's for one specific locale, like "ar" or "en". But I need both!

My understanding is that in such cases I need to do this on the operation level, so it's something like:

```
db.items.find({"field": "value"}).sort({"field" : -1}).collation({"locale": "ar"})
```

However, this requires many changes. Isn't there a better way? Can I somehow make all collections support both Arabic and English "globally"?

EDIT:

Just some clarification. All I need is this:

- People search by keyword
- That keyword could be in english or Arabic
- I want to find() documents whose title, description or name contains the keyword. It's a regexp search.

This might not require special collation setup at all, right? I just tested it and it seems to work with the default collation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly this is not support, from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#operations-that-support-collation)

> You cannot specify multiple collations for an operation. For example, you cannot specify different collations per field, or if performing a find with a sort, you cannot use one collation for the find and another for the sort.

There isn't really a "one solution fit all" for this, really depending on your needs. What I would personally do is preprocess the data to match my needs.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm not even sure I need collation here, because I don't want to sort in arabic or do special string comparison. All I want is to find() documents by keyword and the keyword could be either in arabic or english.
Btw What do you mean by preprocessing the data?

Comment: collation adds "rules" for the query based on the language and the collation "value", for example lowercasing strings. you can pre-process all these "rules" (lowercasing data etc) in advance thus making it redundant. obviously this creates overhead but that's how you can deal with that.

Comment: OK I see thanks. One question: many operations also support collation. For example, find() supports it. So can't I just detect locale (from request) and set the desired collation based on that?

Comment: You could, but you can't do it on multiple different collations if you're querying multiple languages at once.